# Navbar links are not collapsing correctly, they are stacking

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and trying to use a navbar in my project, but for some reason, the links in my menu aren't collapsing until 768px. Before that, they are just trying to stack as if floating. I'm thinking maybe the logo images have something to do with it? Any help is appreciated. My html and custom css code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
@font-face {
  font-family: coalition;
  src: url(C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/Hanamura/waw/public/fonts/Coalition_v2_.woff); }

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/Hanamura/waw/public/img/char_bgs/bastion.png"), url("C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/Hanamura/waw/public/img/bgs/hanamura.jpg");
  background-position: center 151px, center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white; }

header {
  background: #000 url("C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/Hanamura/waw/public/img/header_bg.jpg") repeat-x;
  height: 151px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; }

.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  font: 2em coalition, sans-serif;
}

img.no-float {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
}

.navbar ul.nav li a {
    padding: 30px;
    color: white;
}

.navbar ul.nav li a.login {
    padding: 30px;
    background-image: url(C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/Hanamura/waw/public/img/bnet_login.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 300px;
}

.navbar ul.nav li a:hover {
    color: #bc7017;
}

@media (max-width: 769px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
        background-color: rgba(30, 33, 36, 0.3);
    }
}

main {
  margin-top: 500px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: #000;
  clear: both;
  border-top: 8px solid #bc7017;
  }

section {
  background-color: #1e2124;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

  section h1 {
    background-color: #bc7017;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 18px 40px;
    font-family: coalition, sans-serif; }
  section p {
    margin: 20px 15px; }

section.col-lg-8 {
  padding: 0;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #000; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class='container-fluid'>
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive no-float" src="C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/Hanamura/waw/public/img/waw_logo.png"></a>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Rules</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="login"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you add examples of what your code is doing and what you expect it to be doing?

Comment: I dont see any issues, this is the normal Bootstrap behaviour. Bootply with your code (without custom CSS): http://www.bootply.com/4rXFpZJ4xW